# Is kiddushin which a man was coerced to do valid

Tags: halacha, marriage, beit-din-court, kiddushin-eirusin, even-haezer

According to Halacha, if a man was coerced/forced to do kiddushin to a woman, under threat of penalty (from say a Beit Din) is that a valid kiddushin? Or no, since this was done against his true  will is it invalid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Bava Basra 48b (as well as numerous other places, see מסורת הש׳׳ס), the Gemara says "תליוה וקדיש קידושיו קידושין" - "if he 'hung' her [aka forced her] to accept Kiddushin, it is effective". However, the Gemara retracts this, and concludes that it is *ineffective*, through the mechanism of אפקעינהו רבנן לקידושין מיניה, the Rabbis revoked his קידושין. How this works is beyond the scope of this question.

However, a number of ראשונים, Ramban and Rashba among them, infer than since the Gemara only rejects תליוה וקדיש, *he* hung *her*, but not תליוהו וקדיש, *he was forced* to do קידושין, that in this case, it is effective. This is the way the Rambam rules (אישות ד:א).